# Splunk Log - Date comparison

Tags: logging, splunk, splunk-calculation, splunk-query

I have configured my application logs over splunk and want to do the following -

1. Get events when the string has today's date
2. Get events when the string has tomorrow's date.

I have tried to write a query as below for #1, but it doesn't seem to return anything

```
REGAVAIL | eval Date=strftime(strptime(Date, "%m%d%Y"), "%m%d%Y") | where Date>= strftime(now(), "%m%d%Y")
```

My search string is REGAVAIL and all events are in the below format -

REGAVAIL|00958645030|8871|1|61745|01262017|0|N|N|Y|N|Y|N|N|O|O|O|O|O|O|O|1013|F
REGAVAIL|00958647200|8871|1|61745|01282017|0|N|N|Y|N|Y|N|N|O|O|O|O|O|O|O|1013|F
REGAVAIL|00958649200|8871|1|61745|01292017|0|N|N|Y|N|Y|N|N|O|O|O|O|O|O|O|1013|F

I want to first extract date from it - 01262017and then compare it with today's date. If the match is found, that event should be considered.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are your events just getting a timestamp of _indextime? i.e. as soon as they arrive in your application log they are being sent to Splunk by a UF/HF?

Comment: Ah ok just spotted the date in the 6th field I think.

Comment: yes, its the sixth field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This search creates two strings based on a. event _time and b. the current date using now().  Then we'll create a new field called match to contain Yes or No for whether the event _time matches the relative time that we've calculated.

   `index=yourindex "REGAVAIL"
   | eval eventTime = strftime(_time, "%Y-%m-%d")
   | eval timeNow = strftime(relative_time(now(),"@d"), "%Y-%m-%d")
   | eval match=if(eventTime=timeNow, "Yes", "No")
   | search match="Yes"`
2. The second search is pretty much the same.  The only thing I've changed is the parameter sent to the relative_time function.  It's now set to -1d@d which returns yesterday's date.

   `index=yourindex "REGAVAIL"
   | eval eventTime = strftime(_time, "%Y-%m-%d")
   | eval timeNow = strftime(relative_time(now(),"-1d@d"), "%Y-%m-%d")
   | eval match=if(eventTime=timeNow, "Yes", "No")
   | search match="Yes"`

In theory you can modify this relative_time function to look 2 days ahead, 3 days behind etc.

Hope this helps.  Shout if you have any problems.

Comment: Thanks. How should I replace EventDate? I don't have any such column based setup. Event appears exactly like the picture above.

I am using _time to pick the events date. I just need a mechanism now to pick the date from the event -- 01262017.

Comment: EventDate is being regex'd out of the _raw event.  You don't need to replace it.  If you run the above (obviously putting in your index name first) does it not return today's events?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally I could figure out that below queries would work for me but I got all good pointers from you. Thanks again!!

index=* REGAVAIL  | rex field=_raw "^(?:[^\\|\\n]*\\|){5}(?P<DateField>\\d+)"    | eval eventTime = strftime(strptime(DateField, "%m%d%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")   | eval timeNow=strftime(_time,"%Y-%m-%d")   | eval match=if(eventTime=timeNow, "Yes", "No")   | search match="Yes"

Comment: index=* REGAVAIL   
| rex field=_raw "^(?:[^\\|\\n]*\\|){5}(?P<DateField>\\d+)"     
| eval eventTime = strftime(strptime(DateField, "%m%d%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")    
| eval timeNow=strftime(_time,"%Y-%m-%d")    
| eval match=if(eventTime=timeNow, "Yes", "No")    
| search match="No" 
| eval diff = toNumber(strptime(eventTime, "%Y-%m-%d") - (strptime(timeNow, "%Y-%m-%d")))/3600 
| where diff>=24 and diff <48| sort _time asc